# Booleans as functions and constructing if-then-else

Tags: functional-programming, boolean

I have started to learn functional programming. I went through the presentation by John Hughes, where I have a doubt. Could you please help me?

He says that booleans as data types are not required. They can be represented as functions as follows:

```
true x y = x
false x y = y
```

Then he constructs if-then-else where it takes three arguments: boolean, then branch and else branch:

```
if-then-else bool x y =
    bool x y
```

How would it work in real situation? Let us take the following example:

```
if (age > 18) then {
     issue_ticket
} else {
     dont_issue_ticket
}
```

Th expression "age > 18", can be wrapped in a function like:

```
isAgeAboveThreshold age threshold = 
    ???????????????????
```

I dont know how to proceed in defining the function without "if". How can I define it to return "true" if the age is greater than the threshold? Could you please help?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is talking about [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding). In it, you can represent `age > threshold` (for natural numbers) as `isZero (minus (succ threshold) age)` after defining `minus` and `isZero`.

But this isn't particularly *intended* for practical examples. Just because different data types can be represented in this way, doesn't mean they should be.

> I dont know how to proceed in defining the function without "if".

You shouldn't think you need to; once you know how to represent `if`, you can use it to define further functions.

Comment: Thanks. But how does the isZero work? It should have something within it which is based on if statement, right?

Comment: Not really. The linked page has definition for `isZero`, but you should start with understanding how numbers are encoded.